# Issue with column padding in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

If I use bootstrap column it'd normally set `padding-left` and `padding-right` attributes to 15 pixels.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

However when I add additional class the padding is getting crossed out and isn't available. How to get it back?

**CSS**

```
.alert {
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 alert">
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: `row` has `margin-left` and `margin-right` *-15px* respectively so when you add `alert` having `margin: 0 20px;` it doesn't effect try using something like this `<div class="col-md-12 "><div class="alert"></div></div>`

Comment: `alert` is a Bootstrap class. Probably, it overrides the property. Try using another class name.

Comment: You can add a child div(alert1) in col-md-12, then it's will work proper

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay you solved the problem

Comment: @IshimdarAhamad thank you, It worked

Comment: welcome @AlexanderShmatko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alexander, as Yeldar mentioned before alert is a bootstrap class and overrides the padding-left, padding-right property of the **col-md-12** class **but**as I checked, in bootstrap.min.css 3.3, the .alert class has padding property set to 15 px itself.

```
.alert{ padding:15px;
        margin-bottom:20px;
        border:1px solid transparent;
        border-radius:4px}
```

I ve checked it with bootstrap v3.3.5 css file ( bootstrap.min.css) .

So, your div is getting **back** the padding:15 px values from the **alert** class.
If you inspect the the div element with your browser, even after setting

```
<div class="col-md-12 alert">
```

you' ll see that the all the padding values are still set to 15px.

If I get you right and your problem has to do with the fact that any content you add ( e.g a

element )  inside your div gets more distance from the screen sides when adding the alert class, it has to do with the margin value that you set to 20 px for left and right both.

Because I am not 100% sure about the effect you are trying to achive, let me know if I can help any further.

Comment: Sorry for being late while checking various implementations. At least others above gave a solution to your problem ;-)